# VimWiki - create a "smart" index page for subdir/section of wiki?

Tags: vimscript, plugin-vimwiki, python

I'm using VimWiki for a writing project and for certain sections (like "chapters", contained in sub-directories) I want to create indexes that work similarly to the way VimWiki's diary index works.  Unfortunately in reading through the plugin's source I haven't been able to understand how the `VimwikiDiaryGenerateLinks` function works in order to replicate it for something similar.

My exact goal is this:
In my vimwiki section index page I want to automatically create links to files that match a pattern...

for all files like:

```
~/Documents/wiki/subdir1/string_xyz123.mkd
~/Documents/wiki/subdir1/string_xyz456.mkd
~/Documents/wiki/subdir1/string_xyz789.mkd
```

I want to create a list of links in vimwiki markdown like this:

```
- [xyz123](string_xyz123.mkd)
- [xyz456](string_xyz456.mkd)
- [xyz789](string_xyz789.mkd)
```

Sometimes I'll create new `string_xyz789.mkd` pages from someplace other than this index file, so I want this index file to keep itself updated automatically (the way VimWiki's "diary" index file automatically lists all the diary entries that exist).

The index page as a whole will be structured somewhat like this:

```
# Page Title

Some various content... perhaps multiple paragraphs...

## Automatically generated list of links
- [xyz123](string_xyz123.mkd)
- [xyz456](string_xyz456.mkd)
- [xyz789](string_xyz789.mkd)

Other content that I type manually.
```

...and only the auto-generated list of links should be updated.  I need to be able to type content before and after the list as if I'm just editing a normal wiki page.

Does VimWiki provide a solution for this?

If not could you suggest how to approach scripting this myself?

Comment: This auto-generated list of links is like a very-simplistic instance of 'viewport' concept provided by the taskwiki plugin https://github.com/tools-life/taskwiki#viewports.  Instead of showing tasks, I'm trying to just show files without all the fancy task-related features.

Answer (score 2):

*I haven't had time to test more than the first code-block, but the others are mostly mechanical transformations.*

```
function MyLinks(pat, strip) abort
  return glob(a:pat, v:false, v:true)
        \ ->map({_, v -> printf('[%s](%s)', fnamemodify(v, ':t:r')->substitute(printf('^%s', a:strip), '', ''), fnamemodify(v, ':t'))})
        \ ->join("\n")
endfunction
```

Extracting formatting functions:

```
function MakeLink(text, filename) abort
  return printf('[%s](%s)', a:text, a:filename)
endfunction

function Basename(filename) abort
  return fnamemodify(a:filename, ':t')
endfunction

function NoExt(filename) abort
  return fnamemodify(a:filename, ':r')
endfunction

function MyLinks(pat, strip) abort
  return glob(a:pat, v:false, v:true)
        \ ->map({_, v -> MakeLink(NoExt(Basename(v))->substitute(printf('^%s', a:strip), '', ''), Basename(v))})
        \ ->join("\n")
endfunction
```

You could avoid the lambda by doing

```
function MyLinks(pat, strip) abort
  return glob(a:pat, v:false, v:true)
        \ ->map(printf('MakeLink(NoExt(Basename(v:val))->substitute("^%s", "", ""), Basename(v:val))', a:strip))
        \ ->join("\n")
endfunction
```

(and see `:help method` for how to get rid of all the other `->`s in older vim's; in most cases, you substitute the left expression as the first argument in the right function call, giving

```
function MyLinks(pat, strip) abort
  return join(
        \ map(
        \   glob(a:pat, v:false, v:true),
        \   printf('MakeLink(substitute(NoExt(Basename(v:val)), "^%s", "", ""), Basename(v:val))', a:strip),
        \ "\n")
endfunction
```

)

You supply `pat` (a glob, see `:help glob()`) and `strip` (a pattern to strip, `:help substitute()`). An example:

```
:put =MyLinks($HOME.'/Documents/wiki/subdir1/string_xyz*.mkd', 'string_')
```

How? We

1. `glob` the pattern as a list (change `v:false` to `v:true` depending on how you feel about `'suffixes'` and `'wildignore'`)
2. `map` the results into a link format using `fnamemodify` and `substitute`
3. `join` the list with newlines to make it `put`able text (this last step is unnecessary for `put =` or `append()`; I almost just left it as list of `[k, v]` pairs)

---

If needed you could modify to give more substitute parameters for more control

```
function MyLinks(pat, spat, ssub, sflags) abort
  return glob(a:pat, v:false, v:true)
        \ ->map({_, v -> printf('[%s](%s)', fnamemodify(v, ':t:r')->substitute(a:spat, a:ssub, a:sflags), fnamemodify(v, ':t'))})
        \ ->join("\n")
endfunction
```

Up to you to make any necessary transformations, for now, as it takes me a bit of work.

---

For automatically updating it, you could try something like

```
augroup UpdateThing
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter my-index /## Automatically generated list of links/+;'}- delete
        \ | put! =MyLinks('...', '...')
augroup END
```

How?

On `BufEnter` of `my-index`, we delete from the line below `## Automatically generated list of links` to the end of the paragraph and put our list of links.

(The original version used two commands to delete: the first `/…/+` moved to the line after the header, while the second `.,'}- delete` deleted from that line to the line before the paragraph break. The newer version uses `;` to separate addresses rather than `,`—the difference is documented at `:help :;`. Effectively, it allows the second address to start relative to the first.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117662/discussion-on-answer-by-d-ben-knoble-vimwiki-create-a-smart-index-page-for).