# What does `_` do in this map() expression?

Tags: vimscript

I'm trying to understand the code suggested in https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/28506/6189:

```
function MyLinks(pat, spat, ssub, sflags) abort
  return glob(a:pat, v:false, v:true)
        \ ->map({_, v -> printf('[%s](%s)', fnamemodify(v, ':t:r')->substitute(a:spat, a:ssub, a:sflags), fnamemodify(v, ':t'))})
        \ ->join("\n")
endfunction
```

...and this `map({_,...` syntax confuses me.

`:h map()` says: `map({expr1}, {expr2})` and states: "Replace each item in {expr1} with the result of evaluating {expr2}".

So map is using the input from `glob(...)` as its first argument, and this `{long..bunch..of..stuff}` is the second argument.  That makes sense.  But "long bunch of stuff" begins with `{_,`.  What is that?  What is `_`?

Comment: PS https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117662/discussion-on-answer-by-d-ben-knoble-vimwiki-create-a-smart-index-page-for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See my answer to your other question about `v`: [What is `v` in this vimscript?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/what-is-v-in-this-vimscript)

`_` is the chosen name for the key/index parameter of the lambda. As it isn't used, `_` is used to say *ignored/unused*.

Comment: Note that unlike some languages, `_` doesn't get treated any different from any other variable name as far as I know; one of the side-effects is that you can't have multiple parameters named `_` in your function signature, which is sometimes useful if you want to ignore more than one parameter.