# why are variabes prefixed with `a:`?

Tags: vimscript

I'm trying to understand the code suggested in https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/28506/6189:

```
function MyLinks(pat, spat, ssub, sflags) abort
  return glob(a:pat, v:false, v:true)
        \ ->map({_, v -> printf('[%s](%s)', fnamemodify(v, ':t:r')->substitute(a:spat, a:ssub, a:sflags), fnamemodify(v, ':t'))})
        \ ->join("\n")
endfunction
```

Parameters are defined `MyLinks(pat, spat, ssub, sflags)` but when they're used in the function like `substitute(a:spat, a:ssub, a:sflags)` they're each prefixed with `a:`.

Why?  What's that do?

Comment: PS. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117662/discussion-on-answer-by-d-ben-knoble-vimwiki-create-a-smart-index-page-for

Answer (score 5):

In vim script (vim 8.x and older), a variable can belong to one of a number of scopes.  While it's true it's idiosyncratic as no other language has this feature, it's also consistent as no other language has e.g., "buffer variables."

```
buffer-variable    b:     Local to the current buffer.
window-variable    w:     Local to the current window.
tabpage-variable   t:     Local to the current tab page.
global-variable    g:     Global.
local-variable     l:     Local to a function.
script-variable    s:     Local to a :source'ed Vim script.
function-argument  a:     Function argument (only inside a function).
vim-variable       v:     Global, predefined by Vim.
```

For the most part, you can think of `a:` as merely a marker for "argument" as they are special (and otherwise ambiguous) in the language's grammar.  For instance,

```
string[a:var]     " index by argument  
string[a : var]   " slice
```

However, each of these scopes are *also* exposed as a dictionary so `a:['arg']` and `a:.arg` are also technically valid (but not recommended).

vim9 script introduces `def` functions, where the prefix is removed.  Arguments then behave similarly to python accessible by name alone.

```
def MyFunc(...itemlist: list<number>)
      for item in itemlist
```

Answer (score 2):

*"Why?"*

Having to explicitly write `a:` to access parameter values while formal parameter names are defined without the `a:` scope in the function definition is a very old choice. Note: in this case, `a:` stands for *argument*. IMO if you really want to know why this choice has been made, you'd better ask on vim-dev mailing. I guess it is needed to distinguish parameters from local variables as `l:` is the default scope, and unique implicit scope in function definitions.

Note; this behaviour is really unique in vimscripts as elsewhere `s:`, `b:`, `w:` and `t:` are always mandatory, `l:` is the default within a function definition (and IIRC, it's explicitly required when used to define a closure), `g:` is the default outside function definitions (script and command-line level), but required in function definitions.

Later on, the single `a:` (contrary to `a:xxx`) has been introduced: it's a dictionary with all the function parameters.